# Mysql View ends with no result

Tags: mysql

When i am trying to select columns from multiple views in MYSQL (i used 3 views combine ) result in infinitely waiting no result has been shown.(no error and no error in log file also)
But when i execute those 3 views individually it will run fine.

( i have try to execute 2 view (out of 3)with simple select statement i.e. selecting columns from 2 view without join or where condition then also no result)

```
SELECT * 
FROM   fm.v_time_detail_task_rate vtdtr 
       JOIN fm.v_timehin_fin_period vtifiip 
         ON vtdtr.time_id = vtifiip.time_id 
            AND vtdtr.timedate = vtifiip.timedate 
       LEFT JOIN fm.v_ur_task_assigned_supervisor_firm uc 
              ON vtdtr.user_id = uc.user_id 
                 AND vtdtr.taskorder_id = uc.taskorder_id 
ORDER  BY vtdtr.classification_id DESC;
```

Comment: Any chance you're accidentally running a cartesian product (aka cross join)?

Comment: @mrks i don't think so because when i try to fetching two or even one columns from 2 views it's ends in infinitely.

Comment: why dont post the real query, because `from view1, view2` is cartesian product. How many rows are on each view?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza in fm.v_time_detail_task_rate vtdtr (35 rows), fm.v_timehin_fin_period vtifiip(21 rows)  and fm.v_ur_task_assigned_supervisor_firm uc(78 rows)